# BUG - Google Plus Share URL

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, safari, google-plus

### Environment

- Google Chrome 61.0.3163.79, Windows 7 x64
- Safari, iPhone 6 (iOS 10.3.3)

### Introduction

I want to share a URL on Google+.

In Safari or Chrome, navigate to https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk.

### Expected

The share page appears where I can select the community to share to and type a message.

### Actual

In Safari or Chrome (using Device Toolbar + iPhone 6 profile), I am redirected to https://plus.google.com.

In any normal desktop browser, the share page appears as expected.

Comment: I am also facing same issues, above share link redirect me to direct google+ place instead of asking post.
It is working in android, even desktop safari browser.
Just not working in iOS web view even iPhone Safari browser.

Comment: Yes, still persistent trying to add a Google+ share url to an app and while this format: https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://app.h7.org/live/#YouTube works fine on PC/Mac, it fails to load content to be shared on iPhone/iPad